# Is there a way to view remote hidden files through FTP in Windows 8/10 explorer?

Tags: windows-8, ftp

I have a remote virtual macgine that runs Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. I installed on that remote machine `vsftpd`. Therefore I can access folders on that remote machine through FTP.

My goal is to make my life simpler so on my Windows 8 machine (local), I created a new network location in the Windows Explorer. To be specific, while on “This PC,” I right-clicked -> add a network location, and typed the URL `ftp://RemoteUbuntuServerDomain.org`. I was indeed able to view the files the way I wanted but I cannot see the hidden file; files starting with a dot.

For example `.ssh` on my home folder or `.git`/`.gitignore` on my git folders. Can I somehow view those files? The “view hidden files and folders” option from Windows explorer is already enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the `force_dot_files=YES` option in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file at the remote machine